# Como passar esse código JQuery em Javascript puro

Tags: javascript

```
$(".checkbox-menu").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
   $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
});

$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar `document.addEventListener` verificando com `event.target` qual elemento foi clicado (`click`) ou modificado (`change`) (o `event` é o primeiro argumento do callback, onde eu posso dar um nome qualquer. No caso coloquei apenas `e`):

```js
document.addEventListener("change", function(e){
   var el = e.target; // elemento alterado
   if(el.closest(".checkbox-menu")){ // verifico se ele está dentro da classe
      el.closest("li").classList.toggle("active", this.checked);
   }
});

document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   var el = e.target;
   // aqui eu verifico se o elemento clicado é filho de .allow-focus
   // inclusive os nós de texto, ou o próprio .allow-focus
   if(el.classList.contains("allow-focus") || el.closest(".allow-focus")){
      console.log(".allow-focus clicado");
      e.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```

```css
.active{
   color: red;
}

.allow-focus{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checkbox-menu">
   <li>
      <input type="checkbox"> Item 1
   </li>
   <li>
      <input type="checkbox"> Item 2
   </li>
</ul>
<span class="allow-focus">
   <input type="checkbox"> clique aqui
   <br>
    clique aqui também, ou em qualquer área vermelha
</span>
```